# Difficulty proving the claim $V = \operatorname{null }(T^k)\oplus\operatorname{range}(T^k)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am required to prove the following claim

> **Proposition**. Given that $T:V\to V$ is a linear map prove that for some positive integer $k$ we have $V = \operatorname{null }(T^k)\oplus\operatorname{range}(T^k)$.

I have spent a considerable amount of  time thinking about this and so far have not been able to come up with much Any Hints on how to get started?

Comment: Have you learnt about Jordan normal form?

Comment: @RabMakh No Sorry Not YET

Comment: Hint: $\,V\supseteq TV\supseteq T^2V\supseteq \cdots\,$ and $V$ has finite dimension.